# Nautilus cannot handle "computer" locations

Tags: 12.04, nautilus

When I Run Naultilus as Root by Command: `gksudo nautiuls` It works Well.

But When I Click On menu-bar Go to Computer, I get Error:

"Could not display "computer:".", "Nautilus cannot handle "computer" locations."

How to Solve, is there any problem in ./config?

[image]

As normal user (not sudo(root)) Nautilus Properly Display Computer As Below
[image]

Comment: You can try making sure that `ubuntu-desktop` is installed (and that everything is updated).